# Really weird box-shadow transition bug

Tags: javascript, html, css

so recently I stumbled upon a really weird bug with transitioning a box-shadow...

When hovering over the divs, a box-shadow (black, 5px spread) is applied with a transition.
When leaving the divs with the cursor, the box-shadow spread is again set to 0px.

**The weird thing**: when the div is displayed with a %-based positioning (e.g. left: 1%), the box-shadow is not cleared up properly. Some remnants of it are still visible - cf. red divs in JSFiddle.

**It gets weirder**: the position and shape of the leftover box-shadow varies. It seems to be somehow related to the screen width. In the JSFiddle, just move the vertical resize bar and hover again...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xo3ej74u)

CSS

```
.a, .b, .c, .d {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
    position: relative;
}
.a, .b {
    background-color: #6c6;
}
.c, .d {
    background-color: #c66;
}
.b {
    left: 50px;
}
.c {
    left: 1%;
}
.d {
    left: 2%;
}
.a:hover, .b:hover, .c:hover, .d:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d"></div>
```

Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

PS: This behavior is present in Chrome and Opera. Firefox does not seem to have this bug

Comment: Thants a big glitch i-ve never seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the element, the bug seems to disappear (this is called [null transform hack](https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/))

> [Fork on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpn4vf4w/)

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. How did you come up with this?

Comment: When you have a rendering glitch it may be useful try the GPU rendering and see if the issue still occurs: I faced several issues like yours in the past that I solved in this way, so it was an easy call.

Comment: Unfortunately, the transform hack causes blurry text and wobbly transitions on my website which I can't reproduce on JSFiddle. Anyway, that's another discussion. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and [@fcalderan null transform hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48748402/1218980) fixes it.

Though it should work without it since it did work in the past, I searched the chrome issues and found that it's a reported [issue that should be already fixed in Chrome 67](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=837191).